# Assigning default value to variable in destructing nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I am wondering how to assign default values when destructing a nested array.
 I have `myArr` array which has a nested array `[12, 25, 1, 6]`

```js
let  myArr = [11, 100,  33,  [12, 25, 1, 6], 77]
```

I want to assign a default value to `four` when destructing `myArr` as below

```js
const[ one = 999, two = 999, three = 999, four = [ ], five = 999]  = myArr
```

And I also want to destructure elements of the nested array.

```js
const[ one = 999, two = 999, three = 999, [innerOne = 1, ...rest ], five = 999]  = myArr
```

Is it possible to assign a default value to  variable `four` and destructure the elements of the nested array `[12, 25, 1, 6]` concurrently in one line?

Comment: Personally I'd do this in multiple lines though. You might be able to do this in "one line", but you definetly lower readability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by destructuring the array as an object. When destructuring an object, you can assign aliases, and destructure a property more than once (index 3 in this case).

```js
const myArr = [11, 100,  33,  [12, 25, 1, 6], 77]

const { 
  0: one = 999, 
  1: two = 999, 
  2: three = 999, 
  3: four = [],
  3: [innerOne = 1, ...rest ],
  4: five = 999
} = myArr

console.log(one, two, three, four, innerOne, rest, five)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know an array can be destructured as an object!

Comment: @nibble it's simple once you understand how it works. `let { x } = y` becomes `let x = y.x`. So, `let { 4: fourth } = array` is `let fourth = array["4"]`. You can extend it to anything. `let { length } = string` gives string's length

Comment: @adiga thanks for the supplement, I suppose that works only for properties like `length`  but not for `methods` like `toUpperCase`

Comment: @nibble `toUpperCase` will not have a `this` to to call upon. So, it will be like `const func = "abc".toUpperCase; const upper = func()`. This will throw an error.